# Getting Exception while showing items in AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, exception, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an AlertDialog with a choice of items. I am using the following code

```
final CharSequence[] items={"One","two","three"};

alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Choose COlor");                                
alertDialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                           // of the selected item
                       }
                });
```

But I keep on getting the error on Compilation

> The method setItems(CharSequence[], new
>   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type
>   AlertDialog

I am very confused, as all the examples that I see use this code, then why this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setItems` is a method of `AlertDialog.Builder`, not `AlertDialog`.

You should call all your method on the builder, not the dialog. For example:

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
              .setTitle("Choose COlor")                            
              .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                       // of the selected item
                   }
               })
               .create();
```